# MVC em C#, separar por pastas ou biblioteca de classes?

Tags: c#

Vi uns exemplos que separam por pastas, e outros que separam por uma biblioteca de classes e depois cria o apontamento nas referências. Ambas as formas podem ser usadas?

Comment: Existem alguns padrões, como o famoso "N-Tier Layer" (Aplicação com várias camadas) e o Domain-Driven Design http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2014/10/tutorial-asp-net-mvc-5-ddd-ef-automapper-ioc-dicas-e-truques/, recomendo de inicio você estudar bastante orientação a objetos (OO) e o SOLID http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/04/orientacao-a-objeto-solid/

Comment: Olá Jean, na pergunta eu não quis perguntar sobre qual design-pattern é melhor. Mas sim sobre a diferença, no C# MVC, separar a model view... Por pastas, ou criar uma biblioteca de classes e fazer o apontamento nas referências.

Comment: ViewModel... se você vai utilizar apenas em um projeto MVC, não vejo problema de estar no mesmo namespace da aplicação web... agora se vc já for utilizá-las em um a aplicação web e em uma web api (por exemplo), não faria sentido estar em uma biblioteca comum para ambos?

Answer (score 1):

ambas podem ser usadas sim, porém ambas tem sentidos em seu uso.

Eu geralmente separo por bibliotecas os recursos que são e podem ser acessíveis por outras aplicações, não apenas a MVC, por exemplo se criar uma aplicação que consuma classes em comum, como por exemplo entidades da base de dados, seria interessante separa-las e manter o recurso comum entre elas em outro local (DLL por exemplo).

Já essa questão de pastas eu separo por pastas os meus projetos para agrupamentos e separação das camadas da minha aplicação como um todo, exemplo a camada responsável pelos dados, pela apresentação da aplicação ao usuário final, pelos serviços distintos se houver, etc.

Espero ter ajudado! :)